# Nest Elasticsearch wildcard query works as querystring but not with fluent API

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have about a hundred test documents in my index, built using NBuilder:

```
[
  {
    "title" : "Title1",
    "text" : "Text1"
  },
  {
    "title" : "Title2",
    "text" : "Text2"
  },
  {
    "title" : "Title3",
    "text" : "Text3"
  }
]
```

I want to query them with a wildcard to find all items with "text" starts with "Text". But when I use two wildcard methods in Nest I get two different results.

```
var response = await client.SearchAsync<FakeFile>(s => s.Query(q => q
    .QueryString(d => d.Query("text:Text*")))
    .From((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Size(pageSize));
```

This returns 100 results. But I'm trying to use a fluent API rather than querystring.

```
var response = await client.SearchAsync<FakeFile>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Wildcard(c => c
            .Field(f => f.Text)
            .Value("Text*"))));
```

This returns 0 results. I'm new to Elasticsearch. I've tried to make the example as simple as possible to make sure I understand it piece-by-piece. I don't know why nothing is returning from the second query. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text field is of type [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html), then during indexing elasticsearch will store `Text1` as `text1` internally in the inverted index. Exactly the same analysis will happen when using query string query, but not when you are using wildcard query.

`.QueryString(d => d.Query("text:Text*")))` looks for `text*` and `.Wildcard(c => c.Field(f => f.Text).Value("Text*")))` looks for `Text*` but elasticsearch stores internally only first one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: so basically Elasticsearch is case-insensitive, except case-sensitive at the same time? I tried this and it works. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on text field type you are using. By default it’s text and at the beginning you can think of it as case-insensitive but I would suggest going through [analysis chapter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/analysis-intro.html) in definitive guide book. That will help you understand different methods of text searching.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed your mapping looks like that:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "text":{
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Try this (**Value** should be in lowercase):

```
var response = await client.SearchAsync<FakeFile>(s => s
.Query(q => q
    .Wildcard(c => c
        .Field(f => f.Text)
        .Value("text*"))));
```

Or this (don't know if **f.Text** has **text** property on it):

```
var response = await client.SearchAsync<FakeFile>(s => s
.Query(q => q
    .Wildcard(c => c
        .Field("text")
        .Value("text*"))));
```

Kibana syntax:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "text": {
        "value": "text*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```